# What is this equivalence class like set-theoretic construct called?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I have a relation $R$ defined on a set $X$. For any $a\in X$, I have the following sets:

$$[a] = \{x: R(a,x)\}$$

$R$ is symmetric and reflexive, but not necessarily transitive, hence not an equivalence relation. Is there a name for the sets of the form $[a]$?

Comment: $R$ is symmetric

Comment: You are right.  Deleting.

Comment: A relation which is reflexive and symmetric is a [tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_relation). Thus I would called it a tolerance class.

Comment: Notice that a tolerance is taken to be reflexive, symmetric and compatible with existing operations (in the context of algebra). In the absence of operations, that is, when we have just a set, not an algebra, compatibility is vacuously verified. (Another approach would be to consider the set equipped with operation such that every relation is compatible.)